# Use v4l2convert instead of videoconvert

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, v4l2

I have a proprietary Scaler driver running on my HW. Due to this I see a v4l2convert element in my gst-inspect. I would like the gstreamer to use this element instead of using videoscale/videoconvert when playbin is used. How do I achieve this ?

I can manually create the pipeline as below and the scaling works fine

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=4k_input.h264 ! queue ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! v4l2convert ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! waylandsink
```

However, when I use the playbin as below, gst uses videoconvert/videoscale elements to scale the video down and then passes the scaled down video to v4l2convert element. I would like the gst to use v4l2convert element itself.

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:////home/root/4k_input.h264 video-sink="v4l2convert ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! waylandsink"
```

I changed the rank of v4l2convert element from 0 to 256. videoscale and videoconvert element have a rank of 64, but this didn't help.